# Regex for parsing Wikipedia templates

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I'm developing a tool for Wikipedia, and I'm at a point in which I need to extract the parameter names and values out of the wikitext of templates, such as the following:

```
|param1=value1 |param2=value2 |param3=value3
```

This would be easy enough, but there are two complications. First, there may be spaces and line breaks:

```
|param1=value1
| param2 = value 2
|   param3  =  value  3
```

And second, there may be pipes | inside the parameter values! Like so:

```
|param1=value1
|param2 = [[value2|val2]]
|param3  =  [[ value3 | val3 ]]
```

The expected result would be an array mapping keys to values, like so:

```
$result = [
    'param1' => 'value1',
    'param2' => '[[value2|val2]]',
    'param3' => '[[ value3 | val3 ]]',
];
```

I'm afraid this level of regex mastery is beyond my current skill. Can anyone see the solution? Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: in you 3rd example, |parm3 = [[value3|val3]], what do you want??

Comment: @choz The expected result would be an object mapping keys to values.

Comment: @youssouf What I need is the full value, [[value3|val3]], thanks!

Comment: Don't forget the nested template case: `{{template|a={{subtemplate|x=1}}|b=2|c=3}}`

Comment: "I'm afraid this level of regex mastery is beyond my current skill." - probably far, far beyond. I'm not trying to be mean, it's just a lot harder than you'd think at first. You'd have to deal with `<nowiki>` and other tag extensions (`|param1=<ref>a|b</ref>` etc), nested templates, unnamed templates, parameters whose names are themselves templates etc. Just use an existing library.

Answer (score 3):

You can use already existing libraries like mwclient (https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient) and mwparserfromhell (https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell) to achieve this.

For example code below will extract templates & their parameters from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test page:

```
import mwclient
import mwparserfromhell

wiki = mwclient.Site(('https','en.wikipedia.org'), '/w/')
page = wiki.Pages['Test']
text = page.text()
wikicode = mwparserfromhell.parse(text)
templates = wikicode.filter_templates()
for template in templates:
  print "Found template %s" % template.name
  for param in template.params:
     print "\tFound param %s with value %s" % (param.name, param.value)
```

You will see something like:

```
Found template SampleTemplate
  Found param1 with value value1
  Found param2 with value value2
  Found param3 with value value3
...
```

Comment: @SamWilson: updated my answer, though, I've just realized that your question was about javascript - my apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

```
input = `|param1=value1
|param2 = [[value2|val2]]
|param3  =  [[ value3 | val3 ]]`

var output = input.replace(/[\s\n]*/g,'').match(/\w+=(\[\[.+?\]\]|\w+)/g).map(item => {
    var pairs = item.split('=');
    pairs[1] = pairs[1].match(/\w+/g);
    return {
        key: pairs[0],
        values: pairs[1]
    }
});
/* output:

    [
      {
        "key": "param1",
        "values": [
          "value1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "param2",
        "values": [
          "value2",
          "val2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "param3",
        "values": [
          "value3",
          "val3"
        ]
      }
    ]
*/
```

Comment: This is not a problem you should try solving with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understood, the solution would be this. It will work only if the parameters name or values do not contain `=` character.

```
      var str = "|param1=value1
                |param2 = [[value2|val2]]
                |param3  =  [[ value3 | val3 ]]";
      //Delete line break and spaces
      var splited = str.split(/\=/), len = splited.length, result = [];
      var for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
         result.push({param:splited[1], value:splited[i+1]});
       }

       //result = [{param:param1, value:value1}, {param:param2, value:value2} ...]
```

Comment: This is not a problem you should try solving with regular expressions.